# I'm trying to load a PDF using PDF Box however, the PDF just wont open. I'm not sure whats wrong in my code

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

> "Im not sure exactly what the problem is here so if anyone has any suggestions feel free to hit me with it. I am all ears!"

```
     private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {         
      try {                                      
        //Loading an existing PDF document
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Cayde\\OneDrive\\Desktop");
        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file);

        //Instantiating the PDFRenderer class
        PDFRenderer renderer = new PDFRenderer(document);

        //Rendering an image from the PDF document
        BufferedImage image = renderer.renderImage(0);

        try {
            //Writing the image to a file
            ImageIO.write(image, "JPEG", new File("C:\\Users\\Cayde\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Open"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AFTO781.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        System.out.println("Image created");

        //Closing the document
        document.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AFTO781.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Comment: Wich file are you openning with this line: `File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Cayde\\OneDrive\\Desktop");` ? Did you miss to provide a file name?

Comment: Yes, I did. I named the file "open" to test it. It didn't seen to change anything. I double checked the Location of the file and there was still no change. The Location is as follows: C:\Users\Cayde\OneDrive\Desktop

Comment: Please edit the text of your code instead of putting some image URLs into your question...

Comment: Are you alleging that the PDF file name is named "Desktop"? Not "Desktop.pdf", not "Desktop/filename.pdf"? You can of course name your files the way you like, but it is confusing because the desktop directory on windows (coincidence!) is named "Desktop".

Comment: To check whether a file exists, use `System.out.println(file.exists())`.

Comment: "the PDF just wont open" - please clarify what happened: did you get an exception, did the computer freeze, or did a message appear?

Answer (score 0):

`"C:\\Users\\Cayde\\OneDrive\\Desktop"` is most likely a directory. Your file is likely named like `"C:\\Users\\Cayde\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\myfile.pdf"`.

The File where you are saving the image is most likely also a directory.

Comment: Thats my folder path and the "Open" at the end is my files name.

Comment: @CaydenHumphreys At the end of `File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Cayde\\OneDrive\\Desktop");` there is no "Open".

Comment: @CaydenHumphreys According to the screen shots you uploaded (but not reference) your code differs from that which you show in your question. Furthermore, the code for which the stack trace occurred, must have differed, too. Thus, please overhaul your question and make it consistent. According to the stack trace, by the way, the file in question simply does not exist.